# PL SQL trigger using raise_application_error thows error.

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

I have a few things of code I need help debugging but I feel that if I can get one of them running i'll be able to get the rest(oh how i hope).

```
create or replace 
trigger minimumwage
before insert or update on Employee
for each row
begin
if :new.Wage < 7.25 
then raise_application_error('-20000,Pay is below Texas minimum wage!');
end if;
end;
/
```

I'm trying to do this on a table ran on my school's server through sqlplus if that helps.

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
 was the issue

Comment: i fixed all of my errors on my other triggers except for one that involved count overall i'm really happy i posted this question < 3

Comment: Run `show errors` and show us the real error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're getting an error, it's always helpful to specify what error.  There is a syntax error in the `raise_application_error` call in your trigger.  That procedure takes two arguments, a number and a string.  You are passing in a single argument that is one long string.

```
create or replace trigger minimumwage
  before insert or update on Employee
  for each row
begin
  if :new.Wage < 7.25 
  then 
    raise_application_error(-20000,'Pay is below Texas minimum wage!');
  end if;
end;
```

should be valid assuming there is a `WAGE` column in your `EMPLOYEE` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger deny_dec_pu before update of PU on ARTICLE
 for each row
 declare     
 erreur_pu exception;
  begin

     *insert into erreur values ('Operation de MAJ',sysdate);*

      -- this intruction is never executec why ?          

  if (:new.pu < :old.pu) then
  raise erreur_pu ; 
 end if;
 exception 
 when erreur_pu then 
  Raise_application_error(-20100, 'rrrrrrrr', FALSE); 

 end;
```

/