# Creating a Trigger in Oracle to check date between tables

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I have 2 tables in my Oracle DB

```
CLIENT_ID(PK) -  INSERT_DATE

    1         -  1/1/2017  


CLIENT_ID(FK) -  EXIT_DATE

    1         -  5/1/2017
```

I want to create a Before Insert Trigger that will displays an error if i try to insert  a date on EXIT_DATE that is older than the INSERT_DATE column.

For example if i try to insert 31/12/2016 it will display an error "exit date cannot be older than the INSERT DATE" My problem also is that the trigger must match the Client_ID too between the 2 tables. (I use Oracle 11g)

Comment: Triggers can't display error messages as they have no way to interact with any sort of user interface. Put this kind of checking in your application. Best of luck.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: you can raise an exception in your trigger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449225/pl-sql-trigger-using-raise-application-error-thows-error

Comment: @NikosL24: error checking which is implemented by out-of-line code, as in a trigger, which tosses an exception-bomb into the flow of your code is a mess to create and a mess to maintain. Think about it: you're a nice little application, going merrily about your business, you're half way through a complex transaction, and you go to insert a row into a table. All of a sudden, out of nowhere, an exception shows up on your doorstep! YOU didn't do anything to provoke this, but now it's YOUR problem to handle it. "If only I'd checked for errors first!", you cry, "If only..!!!"

Comment: @NikosL24 I've updated my answer with a foreign key preventing orphaned CLIENT_IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** with info that there is a `FOREIGN KEY` preventing orphan `CLIENT_ID`s.

To generate a trigger that enforces the rule you've described, the below will work.
First, create some test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE INSERT_TABLE(
  CLIENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  INSERT_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EXIT_TABLE(
  CLIENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES INSERT_TABLE(CLIENT_ID),
  EXIT_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX EXIT_INSERT_FKI ON EXIT_TABLE(CLIENT_ID);
```

Then, apply the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EXIT_AFTER_INSERT_ENFORCER
BEFORE INSERT ON EXIT_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    V_INSERT_DATE DATE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT INSERT_TABLE.INSERT_DATE
    INTO V_INSERT_DATE
    FROM INSERT_TABLE
    WHERE INSERT_TABLE.CLIENT_ID = :NEW.CLIENT_ID;

    IF :NEW.EXIT_DATE < V_INSERT_DATE
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'EXIT DATE cannot be older than the INSERT DATE');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
  END;
/
```

**Note**: a trigger is not the only way to accomplish this.  A `MATERIALIZED VIEW` could also enforce this constraint via a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.  Also alternative modeling will simplify things.  I'll detail an alternative a little further below.

Then testing the trigger:

The following is ok:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TABLE VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20170101', 'YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO EXIT_TABLE VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20170501', 'YYYYMMDD'));
1 row inserted.
1 row inserted.
```

But the following is blocked, since the exit-date preceeds the insert date:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TABLE VALUES (2, TO_DATE('20170101', 'YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO EXIT_TABLE VALUES (2, TO_DATE('19910501', 'YYYYMMDD'));
```

> ORA-20100: exit date cannot be older than the INSERT DATE

This should accomplish what you described.

I would add though as an additional consideration, that alternative data models can help with constraints like this.  If the `INSERT_DATE` and the `EXIT_DATE` are both *attributes of the same Client*, that an alternative design with only one table can enforce this more simply:

```
CREATE TABLE INSERT_EXIT(
  CLIENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  INSERT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  EXIT_DATE DATE NULL,
  CONSTRAINT EXIT_AFTER_INSERT CHECK (EXIT_DATE >= INSERT_DATE)
);
```

In this table, the following are allowed:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_EXIT VALUES (1,TO_DATE('20170101', 'YYYYMMDD'),NULL);
INSERT INTO INSERT_EXIT VALUES (2,TO_DATE('20170101', 'YYYYMMDD'),TO_DATE('20170501', 'YYYYMMDD'));
1 row inserted.
1 row inserted.
```

But the following is disallowed naturally:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_EXIT VALUES (3,TO_DATE('20170101', 'YYYYMMDD'),TO_DATE('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD'));
```

> ORA-02290: check constraint (MYSCHEMA.EXIT_AFTER_INSERT) violated

Comment: I think the trigger worked. But i get this error about the trigger. Is it normal? 

One error saving changes to table ""."EXIT_TABLE":
Row 1: ORA-20100: exit date cannot be older than the INSERT DATE
ORA-06512: at ".EXIT_AFTER_INSERT_ENFORCER", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '.EXIT_AFTER_INSERT_ENFORCER'
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @NikosL24 This is the exception you should get when adding an EXIT_DATE that is before the INSERT_DATE, for a given CLIENT_ID.  If you are getting this exception in an unexpected situation, some additional data would help; you can update the question with the specifics and I'll look it over.

Comment: The Client_ID on INSERT_TABLE is PK and on EXIT_TABLE is FK. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @NikosL24.  The existence of keys can simplify your trigger and strengthen the constraint that each CLIENT_ID in EXIT_TABLE must have a newer date than INESERT_TABLE, but won't otherwise change things too much.  I'll update my answer with keys in place.  I should note that a TRIGGER is not the only available approcach.  A materialized view can enforce this constraint, and if these dates are both attributes of the same CLIENT, an alternative model could be used instead.

Comment: Yes i tried it, it works perfectly but i still get the folowwing errors : ORA-06512 and ORA-04088. Is it normal ? the trigger works though it doesn't let me insert the wrong date.

Comment: @NikosL24 It is normal when a trigger like this raises an exception to include ORA-06512 and ORA-04088 along with the ORA-2* (ORA-20100 in our case).  These are helpers to show more clearly what is going on, much like a stack trace.  The ORA-20100 is what the trigger threw, but the database also provides these for context.  The ORA-04088 is an indicator that a TRIGGER (and which) threw the exception, and the ORA-06512 shows where in the TRIGGER the exception occurred.  This way anyone who sees the exception and wants to investigate will know where to search. Does that help explain things?

Comment: Yes i understand now !! Thank you alexgibbs for all your help !